# Bean is not Autowiring correctly

Tags: java, spring, maven, websocket

I am using spring version 3.0.5 in my project. I needed websocket in my project but this version of Spring doesn't support that. So I added Websocket dependency in pom.xml and Implemented A ServerEndpoint like this

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echosocket")
public class EchoServer {

private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
    sessions.add(session);
}


@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {
    for (Session openSession : sessions) {
        try {
            openSession.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            sessions.remove(openSession);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Now I need to execute a service class method, so I Autowired a The Service class the class finally looks like

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echosocket")
public class EchoServer {
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
    sessions.add(session);
}


@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {
    for (Session openSession : sessions) {
        try {
            openSession.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
            List<ProductBid> list = productService.getAllProduct();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            sessions.remove(openSession);
        }
    }
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    sessions.remove(session);
    System.out.println(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
}

}
```

But while invoking the method like List list = productService.getAllProduct(); I found the autowired bean is null and the method is not executing. What could be the possible reason for this? Why the bean is not autowired correctly? And what could be the solution? I don't know is this the correct way to ask but I need help for sure.Please help me.

Comment: You are using a non-spring managed bean so the `@Autowired` is doing  nothing as it isn't a spring bean. You will need to integratie it properly with spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum now I understood what you were saying... OP should check [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support)

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please provide some hints how can I integrate it with spring. I really appreciate any help.